# Eclipse Hotkey to quickly locate a package

Tags: java, eclipse, package

It's like "Ctrl-shift-T" combination, but for package name instead of class name. I have a project with lots of hierarchy package, and when I need to add a new class, it's hard to find the right one.

I think there must be some way in Eclipse to quickly navigate to a package. Does anyone know about this thing?

Comment: Never came across such a shortcut till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Open `Eclipse->windows->Preferecnces->General->Keys`

2) Find the Entry `Goto Package`

3) If not configured, configure it witha key config like `Cntrl+Shift+G` it should be in the `In Windows` type. Now Click Ok..

4) Get your work done with that key combination

Comment: That is a fine solution provided tou are focused inside **Package Explorer**, if not you probably should use Ctrl+3 combination first and start writing "Pac..." to get there.

Comment: Both the tips are nice! Thank you all a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard way of doing this. As a hint I could propose using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> together with wildcards.

Suppose we have the same class in two different packages:

```
com.mycompany.myapp.foo.bar.MyClass
```

and

```
com.mycompany.myapp.baz.bar.MyClass
```

using: `*baz*.MyClass` inside **Open Type** window will do the trick (open the second class inside Eclipse editor).

Now assuming you have **Link with editor** option enabled, now whenever you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new class, your package will be filled automatically from the resource previously opened.

Comment: Thanks Wojtek, this is the first time I know that we can use wildcard inside Open Type window. I'm sure I will use it a lot :)